# using comparisons in tastypie filters

Tags: django, rest, filtering, tastypie

how would i access the the url with comparisons in tastypie? for instance if my filters are set up like this:

```
filtering = {
        "room"  :   ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        "date"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
        "time"  :   ['gte', 'lte']
    }
```

how would i specify the time-range i want in the GET request? i know that *?format=json&date=2011-01-01* will return all on that day, but to filter with comparisons doesn't work e.g. *?format=json&time<=08:00*

obviously the comparisons arent triggered by using standard "<" ">" "<=" ">=" operators so what should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same expression as in the django ORM:

```
...?format=json&time__lte=08:00&date=2011-01-01
```

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering